# Saving the selection of a Segmented control to NSuserdefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using the segmented control as simple yes or no button. I would like to save the result of the selection after I change views by using  `NSuserdefaults` the segmented control has two selections simply "yes" or "no" I have this currently

```
class DetailContactViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var attendingAnswer: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var name : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contactImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var email: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var attending : UILabel!
var contact : CNContact?
var defaults : NSUserDefaults  =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let formatter = CNContactFormatter()

    if let contact = contact {

        name.text =  (contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
        email.text = (contact.emailAddresses.first?.value as? String)
        defaults.setValue(true, forKey: name.text!)
       defaults.valueForKey(name.text!)

    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Comment: i thins you forgot the method synchronize, call it after setValue

Comment: @rohitSidpara calling `synchronize` is not needed.

Comment: @rohitSidpara - if you want to save your userdefault in immediatly, then we need to use `synchronize` else no needed

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Even then, it's not needed. It never is. Run tests, you'll see. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(segementControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        let segmentControl = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        segmentControl.setBool(true, forKey: "KeyName")
    }
    else if(segementControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        let segmentControl = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        segmentControl.setBool(false, forKey: "KeyName")

    }

    //Fetch 
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let segementName = defaults.boolForKey("KeyName")
}
```

Comment: if you save the value in bool type then you need to retrieve in boolForkey not StringForKey